# How to support devices with MIPS arch in NDK r17+?

Tags: android, android-ndk, mips, abi

As you may know, the [doc](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis) says `Historically the NDK supported 32-bit and 64-bit MIPS, but support was removed in NDK r17.`

So how can i support devices with MIPS arch in NDK r17+ ? (what ABI is compatiple to it?)

Comment: I don't think you can as ABI means Application Binary Interface and each CPU architecture does things differently. See this reddit thread on the state of Android MIPS two years ago: https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/4ofdkv/state_of_mips_plus_some_statistics/

Comment: None.  Without support for that ABI, you'd more or less need to re-add it yourself.  Why do you feel you need it?  There are approximately 0 MIPS machines running Android out there.

Comment: @GabeSechan Do you have a valid reference for `There are approximately 0 MIPS machines running Android out there`.

Comment: Well, there's the simple fact that the search MIPS phones android returns no results in Google in the last 4 years.  99.5% of all devices out there are ARM.  The remainder are a few x86 devices, and those are getting rarer (the only real reason to support x86 is windows/android tablets which have failed in the marketplace, and to support the emulator).

Comment: Or if you prefer-  Google Play only lists 3 devices EVER having been made with MIPS-  the Samsung Olleh, the NV310WAC and the gs701b.  All of whaich are API  level 15, for an idea of when they were released.  Its possible that there's some older devices not in their catalog, but I wouldn't expect many.  That's 3 out of 17000 devices they know about.  There's 500 x86 devices.  The other 16,500+ are some variation of ARM

Comment: @GabeSechan +1 for great explanation. thank you.

Comment: @GabeSechan Could you please share where / how you get this information about the "Google Play only lists 3 devices ...", thanks!

Comment: @shizhen Go to the Google Play Developer Console.  Go into your app.  Select Device Catalog.  Filter for all devices.  Then filter by ABI.  Choose mips.  You will see only 3 results, out of 17K+ for all devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't support these devices with NDK r17+. If you really really need to support such a device, stick with an older NDK.